# Airflow 'one_success' task not triggered

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm running Airflow on a 4 CPU machine with LocalExecutor

I've defined an upstream task to be one success

```py
create_spark_cluster_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='create_spark_cluster',
    trigger_rule='one_success',
    bash_command= ...,
    dag=dag)
```

...

```py
download_bag_data_task >> create_spark_cluster_task
download_google_places_data_task >> create_spark_cluster_task
download_facebook_places_details_data_task >> create_spark_cluster_task
download_facebook_places_details_data_task_2 >> create_spark_cluster_task
download_facebook_places_details_data_task_3 >> create_spark_cluster_task
download_factual_data_task >> create_spark_cluster_task
download_dataoutlet_data_task >> create_spark_cluster_task
```

**But even though some are clearly marked as success the task does not trigger**

The 'download tasks' do run in parallel, so that cannot be the issue

[image: graph]

Inspecting the tasks shows:

> Dependency: Unknown
>
> Reason: All dependencies are met but the task
>   instance is not running. In most cases this just means that the task
>   will probably be scheduled soon unless:
>   - The scheduler is down or under heavy load
>   - This task instance already ran and had it's state changed manually (e.g. cleared in the UI)

I've looked at the load and it's indeed pretty high:

load average: 2.45, 3.55, 3.71
CPU is at 50-60%

But that other tasks have already finished, so there should be resources free to start another task, right?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet. Probably going to switch to Celery and see if it helps

Comment: I am seeing the same issue in 1.9.0 and running on Celery.

Comment: In my scenario it turned out to be that my worker did not have the proper permissions to write to the `$AIRFLOW_HOME/logs` directory (this was visible in the `worker` log, however not in through the UI)

Comment: Can you share any pertinent scheduler/worker logs?

Comment: Curious to know whether the issue still persists. If so what is the version of airflow?